# How to increment a date(month) based on the cell values?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

| branch code | month |
| --- | --- |
| TPT | Aug-21 |
| TPT | Sep-21 |
| TPT | Oct-21 |
| TPT | Nov-21 |
| TPT | Dec-21 |
| TPT | Jan-22 |
| TPT | Feb-22 |
| TPT | Mar-22 |
| TPT | Apr-22 |
| TPT | May-22 |
| TVN | Aug-21 |
| TVN | Sep-21 |
| TVN | Oct-21 |
| TVN | Nov-21 |
| TVN | Dec-21 |
| TVN | Jan-22 |
| TVN | Feb-22 |
| TVN | Mar-22 |
| TVN | Apr-22 |
| TVN | May-22 |

> > **I was trying to Derive next 10 months dependent on the Branch Code**
> > To forecast the Business Growth
> > The Formula I used does this magic `ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A21,A2:A21<>"")),EDATE(B21,SEQUENCE(10,1,1,1))))`
> > This brings the output in the same column but I want the output as Branch Code in Column 3 and Date in Column 4
> > Output needs to be

| branch code | month |
| --- | --- |
| TPT | Jun-22 |
| TPT | Jul-22 |
| TPT | Aug-22 |
| TPT | Sep-22 |
| TPT | Oct-22 |
| TPT | Nov-22 |
| TPT | Dec-22 |
| TPT | Jan-23 |
| TPT | Feb-23 |
| TPT | Mar-23 |
| TVN | Jun-22 |
| TVN | Jul-22 |
| TVN | Aug-22 |
| TVN | Sep-22 |
| TVN | Oct-22 |
| TVN | Nov-22 |
| TVN | Dec-22 |
| TVN | Jan-23 |
| TVN | Feb-23 |
| TVN | Mar-23 |

Answer (score 0):

### Count the number of occurrences of that value and add it to a month on the date

```
={DATE(2021,7 + COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2), 1), $A2, DATE(2021,17 + COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2), 1)}
```

[image]

Then to predict different months, just change the number in front of the `countif`.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, 
   Thanks for sharing your thoughts, it does the date increment function well. 
   The alternate way to do the workaround for your shared thoughts would be `=EDATE(B2,1)`. 

But I was expecting the Column A which is Branch Code also to be displayed adjacent to that cell where i put the functions.

Comment: Edited my post, is that better?